# Creating a leaderboard in streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm new to Python and Streamlit and I'm trying to create a leaderboard.
The dataframe looks something like this.

[image: Table]
So the idea is to create a graph that ranks their best results from the selected metric.
I visualize something like this
[image: Leaderboard Graph]

This is the code I got so far

```
df=pd.read_csv('forcedecks-test-export-04_05_2023.csv', parse_dates=["Date"])

sb_options = list(df.columns)

colselect1,colselect2 = st.columns(2)
with colselect1:
   metric=st.selectbox('Select the Metric', options=sb_options)
      
plot_assym = px.bar(df, x=metric.max(), y=df['Name'],template="plotly_white")
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, there are comments in the code.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = {
    'Name': ['Paul', 'Mark', 'Will', 'Ben'] ,
    'Metric 1': [25, 96, 12, 12],
    'Metric 2': [10, 8, 5, 8],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

st.dataframe(df)

sb_options = list(df.columns)
sb_options.remove('Name')

colselect1,colselect2 = st.columns(2)
with colselect1:
   sel_metric = st.selectbox('Select the Metric', options=sb_options)

# Create a new dataframe for plotting. Sort it for plotting display.
# If metric value is the same, display name by alphabetic order.
df_metric = df.copy()
df_metric = df_metric.sort_values(by=[sel_metric, 'Name'], ascending=[True, False])
      
plot_assym = px.bar(df_metric, x=sel_metric, y="Name", template="plotly_white", text_auto=True)
st.plotly_chart(plot_assym)
```

### Output

[image]